# jQuery accessing objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to access the values of an object from a function I created with a callback, but have run into some trouble. I'm still fairly new at jQuery/javascript.

I call the function as follows:

```
siteDeps(id,function(data){
    $.each(data,function(key,val) {
        console.log(key);
        console.log(val);
    });
});
```

The function runs 5 ajax queries from XML data and returns data as an multidimensional object; here is a excerpt showing the meat of it:

```
function siteDeps(id,callback) {
    var result = { 
        sitecontactid : {}, 
        siteaddressid : {}, 
        sitephoneid : {}, 
        contactaddressid : {}, 
        contactphoneid : {} 
    };

...//....

    var url5 = decodeURIComponent("sql2xml.php?query=xxxxxxxxxxx");             
    $.get(url5, function(data){
        $(data).find('ID').each(function(i){
            result.sitephoneid[i] = $(this).text(); 
        }); 
    }); 
    callback(result);
}
```

The console.log output shows this:

```
sitecontactid
Object
    0: "2"
    1: "3"
    __proto__: Object
siteaddressid
Object
    0: "1"
    __proto__: Object
sitephoneid
Object
    0: "1"
    1: "5"
    2: "54"
    __proto__: Object
contactaddressid
Object
    0: "80"
    __proto__: Object
contactphoneid
Object
    0: "6"
    __proto__: Object
```

How can I extract the callback data in a format I can use, for instance sitephoneid: "1","5","54"

Or is there a better/simpler way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with the current format? In most cases an object is the most convenient format to work with.

Comment: @Christophe. The reason for the request is that I can't physically seem to access the second dimension of the object. These results need to be fed back into another ajax call.

Comment: For example result.sitephoneid["1"] should return "5", is it what you mean by second dimension?

Comment: @Christophe I get 'undefined' from that. By second dimension, i mean that 'result' is the first, and 'sitecontactid','sitephoneid',etc are second dimension. probably bad terminology on my part tho.

Comment: A quick live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D9YpU/ . Note the difference between the number 0 (used in arrays) and the character "0" (used in your objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get that output, you can use the Javascript "join" function:

```
siteDeps(id, function(data){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

    var values = [];
    for (var prop in data.sitephoneid) {
        values.push(data.sitephoneid[prop])
    }
    var str = '"' + values.join('","') + '"';
    console.log(str);
    // output: "1","5","54"
});

function siteDeps(id,callback) {
    var result = { 
        sitecontactid : {}, 
        siteaddressid : {}, 
        sitephoneid : {}, 
        contactaddressid : {}, 
        contactphoneid : {} 
    };

...//....

    var url5 = decodeURIComponent("sql2xml.php?query=xxxxxxxxxxx");             
    $.get(url5, function(data){
        $(data).find('ID').each(function(i){
            result.sitephoneid[i] = $(this).text(); 
        }); 

        // callback needs to go inside the ajax call, because it's asynchronous
        callback(result);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, unfortunately, I can get that to work... comes up with ncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'join' of undefined

Comment: even `console.log(data.sitephoneid);` gives 'undefined'

Comment: @user1275268 sorry about that.  I was thinking *sitephoneid* was an array, but it's actually a property map.  See my updated answer.

Comment: @user1275268 ok, really should work now (there was a string typo in "values.join")

Comment: @dbaseman, all I get is " " from that. is there something wrong with how the object is dimensioned?

Comment: @Derek. unfortunately that suggestion doesn't work. I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'join' of undefined. I think there may be something wrong with how I've created the object?

Comment: @user1275268 - Oh well, looks like you can't apply `join` to an object!

Comment: @user1275268 I'm not sure ... I suppose that means there are no properties in **data.sitephoneid**.  What does **JSON.stringify(result)** give you?

Comment: @dbaseman that gives me an empty string. If I run that inside the function, just before the callback, I get this:
{"sitecontactid":{},"siteaddressid":{},"sitephoneid":{},"contactaddressid":{},"contactphoneid":{}}

Comment: @user1275268 can you try the *siteDeps* call above?  And also make the change to *siteDeps* itself, putting the callback inside the Ajax callback.  If that returns empty, then can you post the raw data returned by the Ajax call, so that I can prototype it?

Comment: @dbaseman I must have made a typo with your previous suggestion. sorry, with your adjusted code, I get the following:
`{"delsitecontactid":{},"delsiteaddressid":{},"delsitephoneid":{},"delcontactaddressid":{},"delcontactphoneid":{}}
""`

Just confirming, If I move the callback, that means I have to add 4 more callback commands for each ajax call? (they're not nested)

Comment: @Mawdryn yes, the callback has to be there, otherwise it could be invoked before the Ajax call is complete (alternatively, you could use synchronous Ajax calls).  That could be the reason the properties are not getting populated correctly.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have done the trick. I may need to restructure my ajax calls - maybe nest then, as multiple callback(result) are causing multiple return values.